# Using afconvert to dowsample a wav (LEI16) file

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I read that afconvert can take in a bitrate parameter, like so:

```
afconvert -d LEI16 -b 704000 old_file.wav new_file.wav
```

However, this bitrate parameter doesn't seem to do anything.  I was expecting my file size to get smaller since I am switching from a 48kHz sample rate to a 22KHz sample rate.

What gives?  Is the data parameter (LEI16) overriding the bitrate parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing the command with the @?

for example,

```
afconvert --file caff --data LEI16@16000 --channels 1  fileOutputName.caf
```

or

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@16000 -c 1  fileOutputName.caf
```